# How to iterate through formCollection in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

This code shows all form elements but I want to itrate through formCollection to do some thing with the form element? Any help is appreciated.

```
echo '<h1>view\add.phtml</h1>';
$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('album/default',
array('controller' => 'Index', 'action' => 'add'))); 

$form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
$form->setAttribute('ID', 'creatEvent');

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
**echo $this->formCollection($form);**
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Comment: By the way the form fields/elements is generated by doctrine annotaion.

Comment: I just found out that if you use doctrine annotation that generate form, you can write the below script in the view layer instead iterating through formCollection:  

    echo $this->formRow($form->get('name'))."\n";
    echo $this->formRow($form->get('email'))."\n";
    echo $this->formRow($form->get('mobileNo'))."\n";

Comment: http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Working-with-ZendForm-ZendCon12.pdf